# Pass Query Result to a csv file and Send it as attachement using SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two tasks and since I am new to it, I need some help/advice from the masters.

What I need to do is send the result of q select query to a csv file which can have delimeter as comma or tab and then send this file as an attachement to a particular receipient.

Hoping for some great advice

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) quite easily. A data flow task to copy from the query to a flat (CSV) file, then a task to email the flat file.

Answer (score 0):

SSIS is probably the way to go, but if you want T-SQL to do it, try this..

I'm not going to write the complete program for you, but here are the major points...

determine the split character:

```
SET @CSV=',' --use CHAR(9) for tab
```

build your CSV string one line at a time, looping over the results (do this for each line):

```
SET @FileMessage=ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10),column1),'')+@CSV+ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10),column2),'')
SET @ExecuteString = RTRIM('echo ' + @FileMessage + ' >>' + @FileName)
--append it to you file, you'll need write permissions
EXEC @ReturnValue=master..xp_cmdshell @ExecuteString, no_output
```

actually send the mail, after the file is completely built:

```
EXEC xp_sendmail { [ @recipients= ] 'recipients [ ;...n ]' } 
     [ ,[ @message= ] 'message' ] 
     [ ,[ @query= ] 'query' ] 
     [ ,[ @attachments= ] 'attachments [ ;...n ]' ] 
     [ ,[ @copy_recipients= ] 'copy_recipients [ ;...n ]'
     [ ,[ @blind_copy_recipients= ] 'blind_copy_recipients [ ;...n ]'
     [ ,[ @subject= ] 'subject' ]
     [ ,[ @type= ] 'type' ] 
     [ ,[ @attach_results= ] 'attach_value' ]
     [ ,[ @no_output= ] 'output_value' ] 
     [ ,[ @no_header= ] 'header_value' ] 
     [ ,[ @width= ] width ] 
     [ ,[ @separator= ] 'separator' ] 
     [ ,[ @echo_error= ] 'echo_value' ] 
     [ ,[ @set_user= ] 'user' ] 
     [ ,[ @dbuse= ] 'database' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

SSIS would be your best option. Take a look at this link on how to transport data from your csv file into SQL: [Import Data From CSV](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/import-csv-flat-file-into-sql-server-using-ssis-integration-services.aspx)